# not able to .append <br> element?

Tags: jquery

**I'm not able to get the append (br) to work, but maybe it's because of the initial function?

But appending a (p) works fine.**

```
$(window).width(function ()   { 


    if ($(window).width() < 500) {
       $('#summary').append('<br />');
        $('span.orderType').css('margin-left','45px');
    }
    else if ($(window).width() > 500) {
        $('#summary').remove('<br />');
        $('span.orderType').css('margin-left','0');
    } 
});
```

Comment: "breaking my page"? How? Maybe a fiddle demo would be nice.

Comment: How is this a trigger? `$(window).width(function(){});`

Comment: What do you expect passing a function into the `width` function to do? And what if `$(window).width()` is *exactly* 500? Why would `.remove('<br />')` do anything useful?

Comment: Have you tried using the conditional statements inside document.ready(), instead of inside window.width()?

Comment: This should start like this `$(window).resize(function(){});`

Comment: I think you're looking for something like .resize() (https://api.jquery.com/resize/) rather than .width().

Comment: Also, `$('#summary').remove('<br />');` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: $(window).resize(function(){}); worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need to support IE8 or earlier, I'd scrap all of that and use this CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .big-hide {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

...and put this `br` in your markup:

```
<br class="big-hide">
```

...and do something similar with the spans and their margin.

That uses a media query to hide the break if the browser window is 500px wide or wider. The browser does all the work, no JavaScript required.

If you need to support IE8, then use that same `br` markup and this:

```
$(window).resize(function ()   { 

    $(".big-hide").toggle($(window).width() >= 500);

}).trigger("resize");
```

(And again, something similar with the span margin.)

That shows or hides elements using the `big-hide` class depending on whether the window is 500px wide, by responding to the `window` `resize` event. We also trigger the event to start with, so we show/hide when the page loads. Make sure the JavaScript is *below* any elements it's supposed to apply to (ideally, put it in a `script` tag just before the closing `</body>`).

Answer (score 1):

Try using `..window).resize..` instead of `..window).width`
https://api.jquery.com/resize/

So your function must look something like this

```
$(window).resize(function ()   { 


    if ($(window).width() < 500) {
       ....
    }
    else if ($(window).width() > 500) {
        ....
    } 
});
```

Comment: That addresses one small part of the series of issues.